# Ссылка на передаваемый аргумент

Tags: c++, ссылки

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int F(int a, int &b) {
a = a + 1;
b = b - 1;
return a;
}

int main() {
int a = 5, b = 6;
cout << F(a, b) << a << b;
}
```

По идеи вывод 655 . Но << b выводит 6, почему так? Мы же ссылаемся на неё и меняем её значение в F(a,b). В итоге ответ 656

Comment: Используйте C++17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете `a` по значению. Поэтому исходное `a` остается неизменным, а `F` возвращает увеличенное значение *копии* `a`, т.е. 6.

`b` передается по ссылке, так что его значение уменьшается и после вызова становится равным 5.

Т.е. вывод должен быть 655, но! только начиная со стандарта С++17, который закрепил требование выводить `<<` поочередно. До C++17 стандарт разрешает вычислять аргументы функций так, как удобно компилятору - а `<<` - не более чем функция `operator<<()`.

Так что напишите так:

```
cout << F(a, b);
cout << a << b;
```